# UWP App Crashes on clicking button containing flyout in build 10240

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I have a button with flyout menu inside it, when user clicks on this button app crashes. It work's fine in build version 10586.

Getting Error: "Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement.MinWidth'"

Below is the code:

```
 <Button x:Name="btnMore"
                    Style="{StaticResource DesktopAppBarButtonStyle}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="More"></SymbolIcon>
                </StackPanel>
                <Button.Flyout>
                    <MenuFlyout Placement="Bottom">
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Menu1"></MenuFlyoutItem>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Menu2"></MenuFlyoutItem>
                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Menu3"></MenuFlyoutItem>
                    </MenuFlyout>
                </Button.Flyout>
            </Button>
```

In my DesktopAppBarButtonStyle I have below line which causes error:

```
MinWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.FlyoutContentMinWidth}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pinpointing the error to your style is the first step to solving it. The `FlyoutContentMinWidth` property is a new property in 10586, according to [this diff](http://martinsuchan.github.io/ApiPeek/Diffs/win10.10240.to.win10.10586.fulldiff.html) (almost at the bottom, in fact it seems to be added between 10532  and 10547).

If it would have been a C# code feature, you could have solved your issue by using the [Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn949001) API to check for the availability of the feature, but since it's XAML you'll have to **set your minimum version to 10586.**

> any new resource keys added to generic.xaml and not available in a
>   previous version. The version of generic.xaml used at runtime is
>   determined by the OS version the device is running on. You can't use
>   runtime API checks to determine the presence of XAML resources. So,
>   you must only use resource keys that are available in the minimum
>   version that your app supports or a XAMLParseException will cause your
>   app to crash at runtime.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/version-adaptive-code